# Scroll web page to the according to the added element React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with a button that adds a React input component every button click and I want the web page to auto scroll downward as more components are added. The purpose of this is I want the web page to show the new component and the button.

Right now every time I add a component, I need to scroll down manually to get the Add button. I have no idea how to do this? Can I get some idea how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, so where can I ask this question then? I tried multiple sites that accepts general questions but I get no response. I posted here because I HOPE there is someone that is kind enough to help me out.

Comment: I'm sure someone will help you if you provide what you tried already. Also some code would be nice. You can try putting a React `ref` on input, calcute where is it on page and use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you need to provide more details - e.i create a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io... and provide us with some code... what have you tried? What's not working etc...

Comment: Add a `ref` to your containing component (the one you want to scroll), then when you add a new component, you can just use vanilla Javascript to scroll that container to the bottom (info for how to scroll a `ref` and how to scroll to the bottom of an element in pure JS can be found with a quick Google search). Remember you'll have to scroll *after* the container component re-renders, cos that's when the newly added component will be added to the DOM

Comment: Thanks for recommending me to use ref and scrollTo. I didn't know the existence of ref and scrollTo until now. Love you @Tomasz Bubala & Jayce444